# gorm.io - Filling in prepared statement variables later

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

Say I have something along the lines of

```
db.Where("id = ? AND name = ?", 20, "Zack"}.First(&user)
```

Is there a way to break it up so it's more like this (and this is pseudocode)?

```
db.Where("id = ? AND name = ?")
db.PrepareNextStatement(20).PrepareNextStatement("Zack").First(&user)
```

Basically, I'm working on a query that will have a variable number of conditions. So in some cases I'd want to filter by `id`, sometimes by `name`, and sometimes by both. If I want to make this flexible (say adding a `type` filter) it would be nice to have some code where I could just append that as a condition (have some function to make the `"id = ? AND ..."` string and some function to run a variable number of `PrepareNextStatement` calls).

I have tried just building the string up and doing a `Raw` call, and obviously this works, but is prone to security issues. Need to use prepared statements.

Comment: I believe you want [method chaining](https://gorm.io/docs/method_chaining.html) or [scopes](https://gorm.io/docs/scopes.html#Query).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `struct`, `slice` or `map` to `db.Where`
Take a look at https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Struct-amp-Map-Conditions

```
// Struct
db.Where(&User{Name: "jinzhu", Age: 20}).First(&user)
// SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = "jinzhu" AND age = 20 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;

// Map
db.Where(map[string]interface{}{"name": "jinzhu", "age": 20}).Find(&users)
// SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = "jinzhu" AND age = 20;

// Slice of primary keys
db.Where([]int64{20, 21, 22}).Find(&users)
// SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (20, 21, 22);
```

Or utilize https://gorm.io/docs/method_chaining.html